# Algorithm suggestion to render user information

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, object

I am learning about multi-dimension array/object. I wanted to test this idea and tried everything I could think of but I couldn't find the right solution.

Suppose there are 3 registered 'users' in a game. When they log-in, it will render player information like ID, LEVEL, and HP. How would you approach about building a function for this?

I'm new, so please use vanilla JS. Also, this scenario is just for practice so please don't mention anything about server.

```
<label>User ID:</label>
<input type='text'></input>
<br>
<label>User PW:</label>
<input type='text'></input>
<br>
<button id='demoButton'>Log in</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Outcome</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>ID:</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>LEVEL:</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>HP:</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

var allPlayers = {
    'player1': ['id1', 55, 100],
    'player2': ['id2', 12, 50],
    'player3': ['id3', 123, 1000]
};

*// What kind of function to write?*

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The next function would help you. You can create a function "showObjectData" wich receives an object like "allPlayers" and uses the Object.entries method. From this method you will get an array with all the key/value pairs, and since arrays are iterable you can use a forEach method to print each element and to access element[1] wich is another array you could iterate.

```
var allPlayers = {
  'player1': ['id1', 55, 100],
  'player2': ['id2', 12, 50],
  'player3': ['id3', 123, 1000]
};

function showObjectData(obj) {
   Object.entries(obj).forEach(element => {
   console.log(element);
   });
}

showObjectData(allPlayers);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.